# Ferramentas do Fast Reports não aparecem na tool palette

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, pascal, fast-reports

Estou usando Delphi-XE8 em um projeto que requer a criação de formulários a partir de dados do DB (FireDac), antes minha equipe usava a versão do Delphi-XE4, que fazia uso do componente externo **Rave Reports** da Nevrona, porém ele não é compatível com a versão que utilizaremos (XE8), então foi decidido que usaremos o componente da Embarcadeiro **Fast Reports**, que tem a mesma função que o Rave.

O problema é que estou desenvolvendo o projeto e quando crio uma **Unit**, as ferramentas Fast Reports não aparecem na tool palette, já verifiquei se o componente está instalado (via *Project > Options > Packages*) e ele realmente está, porém não consigo acessar suas ferramentas.

[image: Components]

[image: Tool Palette]

O mais esquisito é que quando crio um projeto novo e em seguida uma nova Unit, essas ferramentas aparecem na tool palette, não consigo desvendar o problema. O projeto foi cirado no Delphi XE8 assim como o novo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast Reports 5.0 funciona apenas para projetos do tipo **VCL**, não funcionam em Firemonkey multi plataforma, como era o caso desse projeto específicamente, então não adianta instalar o componente, pois como a *tool palette* mostra somente o que é relevante e pode ser usado no projeto, estas ferramentas não aparecerão.

A alternativa que encontrei foi instalar a versão **FMX patch B9 do Fast Reports**, é mais limitada, porém funciona para projetos assim.